# Libgdx mesh / material issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, rendering

I am writing a Card Game, using parts of xoppa's Simple Card Game Tutorial. However now I am facing a strange issue when flipping a card. Instad of showing the other side of the card, it shows again the backside (but flipped):
[image]

I am creating the cards the same way is in xoppa's tutorial with the only difference that I am not using an atlas but loading all textures independently. (And this has to stay so as I am loading the textures dynamically).

What could be wrong ? Further, I don't understand in detail why the two sprites for back and front are used and not the material. (To me it anyway seems as if the material texture is shown rather then back/front sprites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that you are using the same code, because that specifically checks for the textures being the same [(`assert(front.getTexture() == back.getTexture());`)](https://github.com/xoppa/blog/blob/master/tutorials/src/com/xoppa/blog/libgdx/g3d/cardgame/step7/CardGame.java#L72).

Quote from the tutorial:

> To solve that, we could use ModelCache which, just like SpriteBatch, combines all cards into one render call. However, it is possible to optimize even more, by not creating a Mesh for each card. **This is possible because each card uses the same texture and thus the same material.** Just like we can combine the front and back side of each card because of that, we can also combine all cards because of that. That would also solve the dispose issue we had to fix.

If you want to use two different textures and can't pack them, then you can't merge those render calls. You could, of course, merge the render calls that use the same texture. Which, I guess, in your case means that you would need to split the cards into a front and back vertices. Then you can use two (or more) batches and combine the render calls that share the same texture.

Of course, there's a reason why texture atlas is used: performance. Using many separate textures will result in many render calls, which requires the GPU and CPU to synchronize and therefor is bad for performance. If you really don't want to use a texture atlas then you will eventually notice that. So, it looks like you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

The obvious solution is to just pack the textures to an atlas, so you can indeed merge the render calls. Having them loaded dynamically doesn't mean you can't pack them. See: [PixmapPacker](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2297).

Comment: That sounds reasonable... For now I chose this approach: For all cards that show the back, I use your approach (stepa). For the few cards that show the front, I use your approach of the card being renderable. There won't be more than 20 cards showing their front. However I now face the problem that the cards are dynamic and include written text (internationalized). So I need to create the Textures for them on-the-fly and I need them 600x800. My first approach was to use an FBO for that, but then they'll get lost on context loss. So using Pixmaps seems like the right approach.

Comment: Oh.. and if the angle >90 and <270 I'd simply switch the material's texture... once creating it works...

Comment: Dont try to solve problems that don't exists. See: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20757&p=86106#p86095

Comment: OK, thanks. Your hints pointed to a good solution. There are still other issues, but going for FBOs to create the Textures and using separate Rendereables for the "open" cards while using the mesh idea (stepa) from your tutorial works. However when doing shadowbatch.render(openCard); before modelBatch.render(openCard) it no longer draws the texture but some fancy lines instead.